# How can I get an Integer from an ActionListener?

Tags: java, eclipse, actionlistener

I'm new to java and I have the following problem:
I added an ActionListener to a button and I want to access a number from it, but it doesn't work the way I did. I seached for it but I couldn't find an answer.
The code looks like this now:

```
public class example extends JPanel{

    int text;

    public example(){

        JButton button = new JButton("x");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();

        add(textField);
        add(button);

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                text = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            }
        }

        button.addActionListener(al);
        system.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your logic. You added the ActionListener to the button. Hence whenever you hit the button, value of **text** is the value of **textField**. But initial value of **text** is null.
In your code, after adding the ActionListener, value of text is printed. You may want to change your ActionListener like this:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        text = textField.getText();
        someFun();
        system.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

To get integer from string, use *Integer.parseInt()* function:

```
void someFun() {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
    ... // Do whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Problem is with logic.

Comment: Yes, it works, but how can I get the Integer outside the ActionListener?

Comment: Check the edits. I think you should have a look at the basics of Java

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare text variable as final at top of action listener.

```
public class example extends JPanel{

final String text;

public example(){

    JButton button = new JButton("x");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    add(textField);
    add(button);

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            text = textField.getText();
        }
    }

    button.addActionListener(al);
    system.out.println(text);
}
```

}

Comment: That doesn't work. Eclipse wants to remove the **"final"**... Is there a way around?